# functions declared on global object

Tags: node.js

If I have the following code:

```
global.foo = function() {
    console.log("global foo");
}
```

These both do the same (output "global foo"):

```
foo();
global.foo();
```

But if I have:

```
global.foo = function() {
    console.log("global foo");
}

function foo() {
    console.log("function foo");
}
```

Then I get different output from those 2 function calls.

If I just have:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("function foo");
}
```

Then a call to `global.foo()` throws an error:

```
global.foo is not a function
```

Can someone explain what is happening here please.

I'm using node 16.19.0

In contrast, if I do the same in browser javascript (using the window object), window.foo and foo are one and the same.

Comment: What's unclear? What was the expected bahaviour?

Comment: Why does foo() call global.foo() when no "regular" foo() exists?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) - *The properties of the global object are automatically added to the global scope.*

Comment: Your edit changes a lot. It's indeed weird that in the browser local function can't be accessed if a global one with the name exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that there is in JavaScript:

- a global *object*: `global` in Node.js, `window` in browsers
- a global *scope*: a top level function declaration and `var` variable are in global scope

---

> If I have `global.foo = function() ...`
>
> These both do the same (output "global foo"): `foo(); global.foo();`

This illustrates that members of the global *object* are [also available in global *scope*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object), as pointed out by Konrad in the question comments:

> The properties of the global object are automatically added to the global scope.

---

> But if I have: `global.foo = function() ...; function foo() ...`
>
> Then I get different output from those 2 function calls.

This illustrates variable / function in global *scope* [*shadowing*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) (masking) their homonym from global *object*.

---

> If I just have: `function foo() ...`
>
> Then a call to `global.foo()` throws an error: "global.foo is not a function"
>
> [...] if I do the same in browser javascript (using the window object), window.foo and foo are one and the same.

On the contrary of the initial situation, variable / functions in global *scope* are [**not** added to the global *object* in Node.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object):

> In a web browser, when scripts create global variables defined with the `var` keyword, they're created as members of the global object. (In Node.js this is not the case.)

(Note: same with top level function declaration as `var` variable)

You could see the global *object* and *scope* as the "same" **in browsers**, whereas **in Node**, the global *object* would be a "prototype" of the global *scope*.